# Spring Security: Session handling on application start-up

Tags: spring, security

I'm using the following for handling sessions in my web application:

```
<security:session-management invalid-session-url="/session-expired" session-authentication-strategy-ref="sas"/>

<bean id="sas"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy">
    <constructor-arg name="sessionRegistry"
        ref="sessionRegistry" />  
    <property name="maximumSessions" value="1" />
</bean>
```

Whenever I start my application (usually on Tomcat 7) and I try accessing my log-in page, it goes to the /session-expired url. Why is this happening? Shouldn't all the sessions be invalidated once the application has stopped? Or is this more of a browser session issue?

Comment: try change invalid-session-url pointing to you login page url?

Comment: In my /session-expired method, I set a "Your session has expired" message to be passed to the login page.

Answer (score 0):

You could still have JSESSIONID cookie on your browser from previous session which no longer valid once you shutdown tomcat, hence you get redirected to the invalid session page. Try deleting your cookies first before accessing the app for the first time after a server start, and check if the behavior is as you intended